# How do I get flex elements not to grow on click?

Tags: html, css, sass

Hobbyist who really sucks at css.

I have the following three divs:

[image]

The problem is, when I click on the middle one, the box grows, and so do the other two boxes:
[image]

How do I make boxes start off and stay the same size even after click. The reason the box is growing is do to adding the "arrow-icon"

Code looks like this:
HTML

```
<section class='modes-flex__options'>
                <div class='options'>
                    <h2 class='options__title'>Options</h2>

                    <div class='options__item-container'id='1v1' onClick="selectedGameOption(this.id)">
                        <h3 class='options__item'>Player vs AI (1 v 1) </h3>
                        <div class='arrow-icon__div'>
                            <i></i>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class='options__item-container' id='1v1-tourny' onClick="selectedGameOption(this.id)">
                        <h3 class='options__item'>Player vs AI (Tournament)</h3>
                        <div class='arrow-icon__div'>
                            <i></i>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class='options__item-container' id='ai-v-ai-tourny' onClick="selectedGameOption(this.id)">
                        <h3 class='options__item'  >AI vs AI (Tournament)</h3>
                        <div class='arrow-icon__div'>
                            <i></i>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
```

CSS

```
.modes-flex{
    display: flex;
    margin-top: 3rem;

    &__options{
        flex:1;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: end;
    }

    &__description{
        flex:1;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
    }
}

.options{
    margin-right: 5rem;

    &__title{
        font-size: 1.2rem;
        padding-bottom:2rem;
    }
    &__item{
        flex: 1;
        padding-right: 5rem;
    }
}

.description{

    &__title{
        font-size: 1.2rem;
        padding-bottom:2rem;
    }
}

.options__item-container {
    padding: 1.5rem 1rem 1.5rem 1rem;
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px lightgrey;
    border: 1px solid lightgrey;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;

    &:hover{
        cursor: pointer;
    }

}

.arrow-icon__div{
    text-align: right;
}

.active-option{
    background-color: $dark-navy;
    color: white;
    
}
```

Tried to set min and max width and was still growing , just want them to stay even width after adding the icon.

Answer (score 0):

You said it: `The reason the box is growing is do to adding the "arrow-icon"`.

In my experience, in these situations, I always added to the default size of the boxes so that when another element (i.e. `arrow-icon`) is added, it doesn't change the size. (Because there is enough space in the box for `arrow-icon` to be added). With doing so, all the boxes remain the same through any actions.

Comment: how do i go about setting a default size of a div? Is it like min width- max width? I tried that and it still grew unfortunately lol

Comment: can you provide a codepen to view and edit the code? I strongly think I can solve it.

Comment: I was actually able to by setting max-width and min-width to 20 rem;

Comment: So, is it solved?

Comment: yes it is my friend